# bcp Utility write to remote server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, informix, bcp, windows-server

According to some recommendations i use [bcp Utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) to write `SQL server` Table to `.cvs` file so i could later transfer the data to `informix` table with the same structure .

> My SQLServer Stored Procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestCVS]
AS
BEGIN
declare @sql nvarchar(4000)

select @sql = 'bcp "select * from ML..gmp4vacationbalance" queryout c:\ss\Tom.cvs -c -t, -T -S' + @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
END
```

---

I have four questions concerning this procedure :

1- How to allow this procedure to write to `remote server` instead of local server `@@servername`,because it's not secure to allow specific server to access my sql server ?

2-How to allow to filter the query under specific condition :
say i want to write query like this :

```
select * from ML..gmp4vacationbalance where balance_date = @date AND emp_num = @empNum
```

3-when i execute the procedure i get data like this:

[image]

Why the third column appear corrupted like this , it's `varchar` desc written in `arabic` ?

4-When i want to delimit by pipe `|` instead of comma `,` like this

```
select @sql = 'bcp "select * from ML..gmp4vacationbalance" queryout c:\ss\Tom.cvs -c -t| -T -S' + @@servername
```

I get the following error :

[image]

Comment: At least I would run the bcp command in the remote server and connect to the SQL Server from there. It's usually a lot simpler to handle errors when you don't have to deal with xp_cmdshell.

Comment: You need to escape | because it has special meaning on command line, try ^|

Comment: @JamesZ :Could u explain more in an answer please

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1: Writing from a remote server**

I assume you meant to say **"from"** not **"to"**. Specify the server name in form `ServerName\InstanceName` instead of using  `@@servername`, you will need to have permissions to access the other server (since you are using a trusted connection `-T`)

**Question 2: How to add parameters to the BCP statement**

BCP is a command line utility not part of Transact-SQL. You can't add parameters. You can format the command line executed. You'll have to make your parameters `@date` and `@empNum` strings concatenate them with the rest of the SQL string for the command line

**Question 3: Wrong characters in output**

Instead of `-c` use `-w` to output Unicode characters

**Question 4: Pipe not working**

A common problem with BCP, simply quote the pipe like this `-t"|"` to make that the record separator

Comment: Thanks a lot ,Could u rewrite my whole command as an example clarifying your four point answer please