# Adding Urdu language text while exporting csv file from MSSQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in my database containing some urdu language text. When I use `bcp`  to export the data and opening the  exported file in excel I am getting all the way question marks there.

What am I missing ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: By mistake .. Sorry

Comment: how about this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32507780 . I couldn't find urdu but I found some on arabic [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+bcp+arabic)

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You're using unicode urdu characters here. Use `bcp -w` instead for unicode characters.